# "ca" vs. "certificate-authority" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It appears that [ca](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ca) and [certificate-authority](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/certificate-authority) are redundant.  How about a synonym?

It doesn't appear that any [ca](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ca) questions are referring to "Computer Associates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ca](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ca) has been eaten by a grue named [certificate-authority](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/certificate-authority).